# PDO advanced search from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am  trying to create a person search, based on multiple `select boxes`, `radio buttons` and `dropdowns`.

Some of the select boxes are arrays so I need to consider all of the selected options to show the results.

There are different tables for services, languages, about, work experience etc.

But something is wrong with my logic. At the moment, when I am trying the search it goes like this: I select English language from the language dropdow, but there is nobody who speaks English so there are no results which is correct. Then if I select one of the services (let's sat cleaning), then there will be one result because the same person has listed cleaning as their service, but this is wrong because he doesn't speak English.

I am using `union all` and `LIKE` in my query, but can somebody tell me why it still showing results? If i am doing something wrong, could you please point me in the right direction?

This is my query and PHP code so far:

```
if (isset($_POST['userServices']) && !empty($_POST['userServices'])){
    $userServices = $_POST['userServices'];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($userServices); $i++) {
       $services = $userServices[$i];
    }
}
if (isset($_POST['languagesArray']) && !empty($_POST['languagesArray'])){
    $languagesArray = $_POST['languagesArray'];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($languagesArray); $i++) {
        $languages = $languagesArray[$i];
    }
}
$search = $user_home->runQuery("

    SELECT nanny_services.user_id, userFirstName 
    FROM hoidja.nanny_services 
    JOIN services on nanny_services.service_id = services.service_id 
    JOIN tbl_users ON tbl_users.user_id = nanny_services.user_id 
    WHERE (services.service_id LIKE :service_id) 
    GROUP BY nanny_services.user_id;

    UNION ALL

    SELECT user_language.user_id, userFirstName 
    FROM hoidja.user_language 
    JOIN languages on user_language.user_language_id = languages.user_language_id 
    JOIN tbl_users ON tbl_users.user_id = user_language.user_id 
    WHERE (languages.user_language_id LIKE :language_id) 
    GROUP BY user_language.user_id

    ");
$search->execute(array(
    ':service_id'     => $services, 
    ':language_id'    => $languages, 

));
$search_results = $search->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
    echo json_encode($search_results);
```

Comment: `UNION` is the set equivalent of `OR` you need the set equivalent of `AND` which is `INTERSECT`

Comment: You should use one single query with JOIN instead of union

Comment: @YourCommonSense lets say I need to query 10 tables with one search.  Is this reasonable? Or can I do it any other way?

Comment: I don't know 10 tables. What I see here is a superfluous query to languages table

Comment: Besides, there is another problem with your code. $languages always contain only single language id. but that's another question

Comment: @YourCommonSense oh okay. did not notice that. So I can use as many joins as possible?

Comment: I have no idea. Because I have no idea what tables you have

Comment: @YourCommonSense I have work experience, education experience,  children_count, about. Would you like the schema?

Comment: Is that all separate tables you are talking about? I am curious, what are columns for the  children_count table then?

Comment: @YourCommonSense all different yes. For children_count there is user_id and child_count

Comment: Why on the earth can't you simply put children_count field into users table?

Comment: @YourCommonSense there are different user types. In users_table I store all the login information and such.

Comment: I don't understand your structure than. probably you need both join and union but I am not sure

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
SELECT nanny_services.user_id, userFirstName 
FROM hoidja.nanny_services 
JOIN services on nanny_services.service_id = services.service_id 
JOIN tbl_users ON tbl_users.user_id = nanny_services.user_id 
WHERE (services.service_id = :service_id) 
AND (languages.user_language_id = :language_id)
GROUP BY nanny_services.user_id;
```

without UNION